# Confusion about wcout and cout, wstring and string

Tags: c++, string

I have a class which holds a single wstring.
I have 2 printing functions one for `ostream` and one for `wostream`.

I **must** use them like this:

```
 MyClass<char> s;
 s.push_back( 'H' );
 s.push_back( 'i' );
 //Printing with ostream   
 s.print( std::cout );

 MyClass<wchar_t> w;
 w.push_back( L'C' );
 w.push_back( L'+' );
 //Printing with wostream
 w.print( std::wcout );
```

My problem is, i cannot make a function to work with `ostream`, here is my class:

```
template<typename T>
MyClass{

private:

std::wstring *data;

public:

void push_back(const T& t) {

    data->push_back(t);
}
    //Does not work
void print(std::ostream& out) const{

    out<<*data;  //Results in a compile error

}
    //Does work verry well
void print(std::wostream& out) const {
    out << *data;
}


};
```

How can i achive this?

P.S.: I know this is nonsense, but in fact this is in a school exam which i had last year. So i cannot change the standards. This is the task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're storing a `std::wstring` regardless of whether the template type `T` is `char` or `wchar_t`. Instead, you want to use the template `std::basic_string` with the appropriate type:

```
std::basic_string<T> *data;
```

`std::string` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`, and `std::wstring` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`.

Similarly, `std::ostream` is just a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<char>`, and `std::wostream` is just a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>`, so you could have a single `print` function that takes a `std::basic_ostream` templated on the appropriate type.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi See my addition about the `print` function.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi I'm also not sure if this is just because your code is incomplete, but your `data` pointer is uninitialised. You need to point it at something (or just make it not a pointer).

Comment: Oh yes, that is in the constructor i delete for more clear code view.

Answer (score 4):

Store the correct type of string

```
std::basic_string<T> data;
```

and overload for just the correct `basic_ostream` specialisation, not for both `ostream` and `wostream`:

```
void print(std::basic_ostream<T> & out) const {
    out << data;
}
```

(Also, storing the string itself rather than an uninitialised pointer will give better results).